# Includes not covering select list

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have tables 2 tables in my query.  I created a nonclustered index on the join and where clause columns and included the select list.  When I run the query and look at the execution plan and statistics IO, I see that the logical reads have not went down.  After replacing the select list with select 1, I see a dramatic decrease in the logical reads.  The database is SQL 2005 SP2.

1 of the indexes are being used (but not the include).  The other is being completely ignored (different issue).  Any insight as to why my include is being ignored would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the query & indexes:

```
SELECT 
    cm.col1
    ,cm.col2
    ,cm.col3
    ,cm.col4
    ,cm.col5
    ,cm.col6
    ,cp.col7
    ,cm.col8
    ,cm.col9
    ,cp.col10
FROM table1 cm  
INNER JOIN table2 cp 
    ON cm.col1 = cp.col11  
INNER JOIN table3 c 
    ON cp.col7 = C.col12
WHERE C.col13 = @Variable
and cm.col9 IN ('value1', 'value2')
```

create INDEX ix_table1_Includes
ON Table1 (col1, col9) 
INCLUDE (col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col8)

create INDEX ix_table2_Includes
ON table2 (col11)
INCLUDE (col7, col10)

Comment: Please edit your post to include the queries and indexes. Your question is too vague right now.

Comment: Did you get the system time to generate the index before querying? It's not instantaneous!  There is searching and IO the system has to do behind the scenes to generate the index(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your query starts from `col13 = @Variable` the problem is that col7 is an included field, so the join can't use it.

If your query starts from `col9 IN ('value1', 'value2')` the problem is that col9 is not the first field of the index, so it can't be used for fetching the rows.

Comment: Wow!  Changing the order of my index made a world of difference!  Thank you so much for that!

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server uses statistics to develop the most effective query plan it can build. Usually that means the least amount of reads or other work. Is the covered index, the one with the includes, producing the least number of rows compared to the index being used? You can set io stats on and drop the index you don't want to use and look at how many reads, logical and physical, is done when each index us used.